# Manually download packages on other operating systems

Tags: wireless, package-management

To connect to the wireless at my sister's university, I need the ca-certificate package. But since there is no internet connection, I can't download it from the repos. How can I manually download it at a Windows system and install it? A .deb pacakge would be most helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find out what packages you need (and the URLs for them), you can use the `--print-uris` argument to `apt-get`. For example:

```
apt-get install -y -d --print-uris ca-certificates
```

That will list everything you need to download manually on the Windows system. If you want to make it really easy, you could even generate an HTML file with the links that you could load on the Windows machines:

```
echo "<html><body><ul>" > /tmp/debs.html
apt-get install -y -d --print-uris ca-certificates | grep ^"'" | cut -d"'" -f2 | awk '{print " <li><a href=\"" $0 "\">" $0 "</a></li>"}' >> /tmp/debs.html
echo "</ul></body></html>" >> /tmp/debs.html
```

Just access `file:///path/to/debs.html` once it is on the Windows machine, and you can download all the required packages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) page.

You then choose your version of Ubuntu. For Maverick, you would find the package you need at http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/ca-certificates. This page also lists all the eventual dependencies you could have to download to install this package.

Good luck!

Comment: Downloading dependencies may become a difficult task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Keryx, an  offline package management system.

Check this url:

http://keryxproject.org/